# Typo3 add a new option or change existing options in backend for Page Frontend Layout drop down not working

Tags: php, typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x

i am clearly missing something, but i can't figure out what. I am developing site on Typo3 CMS v7.6.10. I included my extension configuration in TS template.

In **\Configuration\TCA\Overrides\pages.php:**

```
<?php
defined('TYPO3_MODE') or die();

// Add pageTSconfig
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::registerPageTSConfigFile(
    '/**/', // my extension
    'Configuration/PageTS/pages.ts',
    'My special config'
);
```

In **\Configuration\PageTS\pages.ts:** (from question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9736951/how-to-add-a-new-template-to-typo3-layouts-drop-down-list))

```
TCEFORM.pages {
    layout.altLabels.0 = Normal
    layout.altLabels.1 = Startpage
    layout.altLabels.2 = Landing page
}
```

After clearing all cache, reinstalling extension nothing had changed in Edit page - Appearance - Frontend Layout drop down. Am i wrong and this configuration is for something else? This is just an example of me using `TCEFORM.pages`, my attempts to do something with other elements not working too. Do i need to include registered config file? If so, nothing appears in my typoscript template include options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if you did this but

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::registerPageTSConfigFile()
```

"only" registers a PageTSConfig file for the selection in the page property. To include it you have to go to the properties of a page in the resources tab and select your file there (see screenshot). It is then active for this page and all subpages.

[image: Select PageTSConfig in page properties]

As an alternative you could use `ExtensionManagementUtility::addPageTSConfig()` instead. If you pass the `<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT` string to that function your PageTSConfig will be loaded on every page.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I thought i need to include this config in typoscript template include and i was wrong.

Comment: Yes, TypoScript is only relevant for frontent rendering and has to be included in template records. Configuring the backend is done via PageTSConfig and that needs to be included on pages.